# How to set vertical-align of span to middle of a div

Tags: html, css, stylesheet

I test vertical-align with a simple html code, but it doesn't work

```
<div style="height:45px; border: solid 1px black;">
    <strong style="vertical-align:bottom;">
        abc
    </strong>
</div>
```

Answer (score 6):

This is how you do it

```
<div style="height:45px; border: solid 1px black; display: table;">
    <strong style="vertical-align:bottom; display: table-cell;">
        abc
    </strong>
</div>
```

#### [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Starx/35RdL/1/)

As I have mentioned before, vertical aligns are very tricky. For this to work, like it did on table, set the parent container to display as `table` and the inner `<div>`s or `elements` to display as `table-cell`

Answer (score 0):

Give the parent box (in your case `div`) a `height`, `display: table-cell` and `vertical-align: middle` properties. Here is the example:

```
<div style="height:100px; border: solid 1px black; vertical-align:middle;display:table-cell;">
    <span style="">abc</span>
</div>
```